# Replying to a contact on careers does not update the messages sent count

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On the Messages tab in Careers, the count of messages sent does not update when a message is sent. This can lead you to think that you still have a message that needs to be responded to. Once you refresh the page the correct count is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the report, I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will go out with the next push, sometime this afternoon.  As a bonus, the count in parenthesis in the list will increment as well.